# how to tell NServiceBus is using MaximumConcurrencyLevel?

Tags: message-queue, nservicebus

I'm trying to validate our company's code works when NServiceBus v4.3 is using the MaximumConcurrencyLevel value setup in the  config.

The problem is, when I try to process 12k+ of queued entries, I cannot tell any difference in times between the five different max concur levels I change. I set it to 1 and I can process the queue in 8m, then I put it to 2 and I get 9m, seems interesting (I was expecting more, but it's still going in the right direction), but then I put 3, 4, 5 and the timings stay at around 8m. I was expecting a much better throughput.

My question is, how can I verify that NServiceBus is actually indeed using five threads to process entries on the queue?

PS I've tried setting the MaximumConcurrencyLevel="1" and the MaximumMessageThroughputPerSecond along with logging the Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId thinking\hoping I was ONLY going to see one ThreadID value, but I'm seeing quite a few of different ones, which surprised me. My plan was to see one, then bump the max concur level to 5 and hopefully see five different values.

What am I missing? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does your setup include a distributor-worker setup or is this a single endpoint?

Comment: Are you running the endpoint in release mode in CMD/Powershell? Are you running the NServiceBus.exe host? if you are make sure your run it in production profile (NServiceBus.Production) from command line or powershell (not from Visual Studio). Is "8m" == 8 minutes??

Comment: Thank you for your replies. It is a single endpoint. And I have done a Release build in VS, and am running from cmd in admin mode. Correct, the "m" is for minutes.

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple reasons why you don't see faster processing times when increasing the concurrency setting described on the official documentation page: http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/operations/tuning

- You mentioned you're using the `MaximumMessageThroughputPerSecond` which will negate any performance gains my parallel message processing if a low value has been configured. Try removing this setting if possible.
- Maybe you're accessing a resource in your handlers which isn't supporting/optimized for parallel access.

NServiceBus internally schedules the processing logic on the threadpool. This means that even with a `MaximumConcurrencyLevel` of 1, you will most likely see a different thread processing each message since there is no thread affinity. But the configuration values work as expected, if your queue contains 5 messages:

- it will process these messages one by one if you configured `MaximumConcurrencyLevel` to 1
- it will process all messages in parallel if you configured `MaximumConcurrencyLevel` to 5.
  Depending on your handlers it can of course happen that the first message is already processed at the time the fifth message is read from the queue.